Nuxt 3 sometimes I can omit .value when using useState, sometimes I can't, why?
Please see this minimum example, if I use useState , normally, I can write something like this:
<script setup>
const num = useState('num', () => 1);
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ num }}
  </div>

  <div>
    {{ typeof num }}
  </div>

  <div>
    {{ JSON.stringify(num) }}
  </div>
</template>

And the result is what I expected:
1
number
1


However, when I move the useState into composables, everything changed, like this:
export const useNum = () => {
  const num = useState('num', () => 1);

  return {
    num,
  };
};

<script setup>
const numStore = useNum();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ numStore.num }}
  </div>

  <div>
    {{ typeof numStore.num }}
  </div>

  <pre>
    {{ JSON.stringify(numStore.num, null, 2) }}
  </pre>
</template>


the result is super weird:
1
object
    {
  "_object": {
    "$s__nuxt_devtools__": {
      "timeSsrStart": 1719387436211
    },
    "$snum": 1
  },
  "_key": "$snum",
  "__v_isRef": true
}
  



Why is this happening? How can I avoid this?

A little off topic, but you should really use the official pinia library if you want to have a separate store for state management

but nuxt 3's useState already have similar functionality, I can set a key and use it as global state.

Yes, but you cannot use it inside composables, the link I added for pinia is actually nuxt's own documentation. At least not the way you want to use it in the question

thank you for your advice, I need to think about it.

This is normal, there's generally nothing to avoid, this is how ref unwrapping works. {{ numStore.num }} results in 1, which is the intended behaviour. Is there a real problem you try to solve? There's no use for typeof or JSON.stringify in a template

Based on official docs :

Ref unwrapping in templates only applies if the ref is a top-level property in the template render context.

By unwrapping we mean not using .value
So try to destruct the return value of your composable to make the ref as  top-level property or use the .value in template  :
<script setup>
const { num } = useNum();
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    {{ num }}
  </div>

  <div>
    {{ typeof num }}
  </div>

  <pre>
    {{ JSON.stringify(num, null, 2) }}
  </pre>
</template>


I didn't downvote, but it doesn't cover the fact that that {{ numStore.num }} is ok. Template interpolation itself forces ref unwrapping. It still makes sense to use top-level refs for consistent unwrapping

Not sure what kind of object useState returns but if you need a .value, it's a ref (not sure why it is not in the first context).
You can also use toValue if you wish to not get bored trying to find out exactly what is inside of your variable.
As for the rest (pinia topic), careful with the singleton pattern in an SSR context as written in the docs yes.
